# Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.priyan.patients.EPrescriber column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, spring-mvc, nhibernate-mapping

Here is my bean classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLETS", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "tradeName")})
public class Tablets implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4854785134773287611L;

    public Tablets() {
    }

    public Tablets(int id, String tradeName, String category, String type,
            Set<EPrescriber> selectedTablets) {
        this.id = id;
        this.tradeName = tradeName;
        this.category = category;
        this.type = type;
        this.selectedTablets = selectedTablets;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="tablets_seq", sequenceName="tablets_id_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE , generator= "tablets_seq" )
    private int id;

    @Column private String tradeName;
    @Column private String category;
    @Column private String type;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="tablets")
    @Column private Set<EPrescriber> selectedTablets=new HashSet<EPrescriber>(0);

    public Set<EPrescriber> getSelectedTablets() {
        return selectedTablets;
    }

    public void setSelectedTablets(Set<EPrescriber> selectedTablets) {
        this.selectedTablets = selectedTablets;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTradeName() {
        return tradeName;
    }
    public void setTradeName(String tradeName) {
        this.tradeName = tradeName;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

and another bean class here

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "E_PRESCRIBER")
public class EPrescriber implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 440529869955257543L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id" ,unique = true, nullable = false)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ePrescriber_seq", sequenceName = "ePrescriber_id_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ePrescriber_seq")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Tablets tablets;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Tablets getTablets() {
        return tablets;
    }

    public void setTablets(Tablets tablets) {
        this.tablets = tablets;
    }

}
```

Here is my error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactsControllers': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.priyan.patients.ContactsDAO com.priyan.patients.ContactsControllers.contactsDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactsDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.priyan.patients.ContactsDAO.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.priyan.patients.EPrescriber column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.priyan.patients.ContactsDAO com.priyan.patients.ContactsControllers.contactsDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactsDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.priyan.patients.ContactsDAO.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.priyan.patients.EPrescriber column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

Please help me to sort out this issue.
thanks

**EDIT**

Now I changed my bean class as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "E_PRESCRIBER")
public class EPrescriber implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 440529869955257543L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ePrescriberid"  ,unique = true, nullable = false)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ePrescriber_seq", sequenceName = "ePrescriber_id_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ePrescriber_seq")
    private int ePrescriberid;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Tablets tablets;

    public int getePrescriberid() {
        return ePrescriberid;
    }

    public void setePrescriberid(int ePrescriberid) {
        this.ePrescriberid = ePrescriberid;
    }

    public Tablets getTablets() {
        return tablets;
    }

    public void setTablets(Tablets tablets) {
        this.tablets = tablets;
    }

}
```

now its gives the below error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactsControllers': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.priyan.patients.EPrescriberDAO com.priyan.patients.ContactsControllers.ePrescriberDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EPrescriberDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate com.priyan.patients.EPrescriberDAO.hibernateTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.priyan.patients.EPrescriberDAO com.priyan.patients.ContactsControllers.ePrescriberDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EPrescriberDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate com.priyan.patients.EPrescriberDAO.hibernateTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework
```

Comment: I think this is your problem: `@JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)` as you already have an id named column.

Comment: dear Jorge Campos. thanks for your suggestion.now thats issue corrected but another error occur
please help me to sort out this issue
[POST edited]

Comment: Glad that it helps. As the StackTrace says there is no DAO defined as EPrescriberDAO. You should post your beans mapper so we can see your configuration. At my end here is late, almost 00:00 am so, I'm go to sleep now. If anyone help you until tomorrow I will continue to help you.

Comment: good night dear Jorge.u r correct.seems issue with my DAO.will checking with that point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main issue sorted with the help of dear **Jorge**

another second issue with my DAO

now its sorted with the below code

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void getTabletbyNameAndSave(String []selectedMedicines) {
    Session session =  HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    EPrescriber ePrescriber=new EPrescriber();
    List<Tablets> selectedTablets=new ArrayList<Tablets>();
    //MY transaction & business logics
    session.save(ePrescriber);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    //sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(ePrescriber);
}
```